Is the following mapping between an equivalence class and a subgroup bijective?
Let $G$ be a group and $U \leq G$ a subgroup. Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $G$ that is defined as follows:
$$g \sim h \iff gh^{-1} \in U$$
Now let $[g]_{\sim}$ denote the equivalence class of $g \in G$. Does the following map define a bijection?
$$\varphi: [g]_{\sim} \rightarrow U, h \mapsto gh^{-1}$$
It is obvious to me that it is injective, since $\varphi(h_1) = \varphi(h_2) \implies gh_1^{-1} = gh_2^{-1} \implies g^{-1}gh_1^{-1} = g^{-1}gh_2^{-1} \implies h_1^{-1} = h_2^{-1} \implies h_1 = h_2$.
I am still unsure however whether it is surjective or not. It seems to me that surjectivity would imply that all all elements of G would be in the same equivalence class but that doesn't seem right.

If $u\in U$ then, letting $h=u^{-1}g$ we see that $h^{-1}=g^{-1}u$ so $\varphi (h)=gg^{-1}u=u$.  And, of course, $g\sim h$ since $gh^{-1}\in U$.I don't see how showing that $[g]$ is bijective with $U$ proves that every element in $G$ is equivalent to $g$.

For intuition, you might want to consider the extreme case $U={e}$.  Then the only element in $G$ which is equivalent to $g$ is $g$ itself.

@lulu Thank you very much! I had thought about constructing h in this way as well but it did not seem clear to me as to why $h \in [g]_{\sim}$ at the time. It makes sense now though, since $u \in U$

If you like, post your version of  the solution below. That way people here can check your work and the site can close the question.

I found the answer thanks to @lulu.
The injectivity I have already shown in the original post.
Now for the surjectivity consider $u \in U$ and $h = u^{-1}g$. Since $gh^{-1} = gg^{-1}u = u \in U$ we know that $h \in [g]_{\sim}$.
It then follows that $\varphi(h) = gh^{-1} = u$, so we know that $\varphi$ is surjective and hence bijective.
